# Kendo Grid - setDataSource is not working

Tags: kendo-grid

Kendo grid is loading the data properly if we set the datasource while creating the grid. If we create the grid without datasource and then try to set the datasource, the data is not loading.

**HTML**

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
   <tr>
       <td>#: LastName #</td>
       <td>#: FirstName #</td>
   </tr>
</script>
```

Kendo grid is loading the data with the below code

```
$jQuery2_1(document).ready(function () {
        $jQuery2_1("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: JSON.parse($jQuery2_1("#PlaceHolderMain_hidJson").val()),
            rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#rowTemplate").html()),
            sortable: true,
            columns: [
                { field: "LastName", title: "Last Name" },
                { field: "FirstName", title: "First Name", width: "120px" },
            ]
        });
    });
```

If I define the grid first and set the data source, kendo grid is not loading the data.

```
$jQuery2_1(document).ready(function () {
        $jQuery2_1("#grid").kendoGrid({
            rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#rowTemplate").html()),
            sortable: true,
            columns: [
                { field: "LastName", title: "Last Name" },
                { field: "FirstName", title: "First Name", width: "120px" },
            ]
        });

        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: JSON.parse($jQuery2_1("#PlaceHolderMain_hidJson").val())
        });
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.setDataSource(dataSource);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using `$jQuery2_1` as an alias.

So, change the line

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
```

to

```
var grid = $jQuery2_1("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
```

Comment: my mistake. Haven't noticed it. Thanks